# What plant is this? (Found in South Thailand)

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image]

[image]

Have tried to recognize with PlantSnap App, no results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Desert Rose, commonly used for Bonsai plantings.

Comment: Good ID.  *Adenium obesum*, in the Apocynaceae as is *Plumeria*, but from Africa (I almost had it!).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a *Plumeria* but there are several species and many horticultural variants.  It's native to the New World.